# Sqlite update boolean value in android studio

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, updates

I am trying to update a boolean value in SQLite in android studio by using this codes

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("Indirme_casse",true);

db.update(TABLE_NAME,values ,"Id=1",null);
```

put the value is stil false please any help !!

my all Code

```
public void Tablo_Guncele(Uygulamalar model) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
            newValues.put("uygulamaicon", model.getUygulamaicon());
            int rows = db.update(TABLO_UYGULAMALAR, newValues, "appId=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(model.getAppId())});
            newValues.clear();
            newValues.put(indirmeBasti,1);
            int rows2 = db.update(TABLO_UYGULAMALAR, newValues, "appId=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(model.getAppId())});
            int sonuc = rows2;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String hata = e.getMessage();
        }
        db.close();
    }
```

when I referesh my data the icone successfully Changed but indirme_case still false

Comment: Check the return value from the update e.g. use  `int rv = db.update(TABLE_NAME,values ,"Id=1",null);` if it is 1 then row has been updated, if 0 then not and the likely reason is that there is no row who's id column = 1. You can check the rows by adding the line `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null));` and then check the log after running.

Comment: thanks for your replay his returned 1 but still false

Comment: try changing `"Id=1"` to `" Id = '1' "`

Comment: If 1 is returned then a row is being updated (*add the suggested line to dump the cursor before and after the update and it should show that this is the case*). The most likely issue is with how you are determining that it is still false. If via a ListView/RecyclerView then odds on that your are not refreshing the underlying data. You need to show or explain how you are determining that it is still false.

Comment: I am edit my code in up   plase can you look to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third parameter should be in where clause try ones the following code

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME,values,"Id = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(1)})
```

SQLite return fourth parameter in "?" third parameter

Comment: it still false :(

Comment: is there any error log I have tried this working fine

Comment: E/Sensor-AccelerometerUI: java.io.IOException: Connection refused
system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '9d6e2b com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
/system_process E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=25, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]

Comment: system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 104)
 E/BstCommandProcessor-Application: Error encountered while deleting file
? E/NFC: could not retrieve NFC service

Comment: this from logcat

Comment: Please check NFC service are you using any device